# CUFON is not working with supersized slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cufon

I am using supersized jQuery slider plugin which change one on clicking NAV anchor

supersize jQuery Plugin:::::::::>

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                // Functionality
                slide_interval      :   8000,       // Length between transitions
                transition          :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed    :   1300,       // Speed of transition
                // Components                           
                slide_links         :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                slides              :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : './lib/images/photos/image1.jpg'},
                                                    {image : './lib/images/photos/image2.jpg'},
                                                    {image : './lib/images/photos/image3.jpg'},
                                                    {image : './lib/images/photos/image4.jpg'}
                                            ],

                bullet: "bullet",
                bullet_active: "active",
                bullet_main: "bullet-main",
                bullet_main_active: "active",
                bullet_main_second: "bullet-main-second1",
                bullet_main_second_active: "active2"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

bullet_main_second_active: "active2" is ACTIVE ANCHOR.

Now Problem is CUFON's not working in after transition.. There is a bug... its not deactive previous anchor. after hover on previous anchor it change the color to default...
slider plugin working fine on default font family.... its cufon bug

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    Cufon('.block-right a h1');
    Cufon.replace('#nav li a');
    Cufon.replace('#rightcaption a', {
        hover: {
            color: '#f04037'
        }
        });
        Cufon.replace('ul.tabNavigation li a', {
        hover: {
            color: '#FFF'
        }
        });
</script>
```

CSS:::::::::::::>

```
#rightcaption {
    float:right;
    padding-top:25%;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#b5b5b5;
    margin-right:40px;}
#rightcaption a {
    background:url(../images/bullet1.png) no-repeat right 8px;
    height:8px;
    color:#b5b5b5;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    padding:4px 40px 13px 13px;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;}
a.active2 {
    background:url(../images/bullet2.png) no-repeat right 8px #FFF !important;
    margin:0 20px 5px 0;
    color:#f04037;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:4px 40px 13px 13px !important;
    display:block;}
```

img:::::::::::::::::>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyjvw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really understood your question then I would say that cuffon has a method that has to be used/called to take effect after any element has been changed (after any transition) and I think you are missing that, so you can call that after your transition has been completed

```
Cufon.refresh(); //Refresh elements that are using coffon font to apply new style
```

I think, somehow you have to invoke a callback function after each transition. Here is an answer on SO [**about cuffon**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906679/how-reload-refresh-styles-of-an-element-using-cufon-font-using-jquery/9907126#9907126) and here is an answer on SO [**about supersized**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904154/how-do-i-use-this-api-of-supersized-jquery-plugin) (answered by the author of the plugin), these could be helpful.