# Reloading Cufon after jquery.load

Tags: jquery, cufon

i know, the problem has been discussed many times here, but i cannot see clear solution. i have tried https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API solutions. this is my code

```
function jload(){
  $('#main').load('ajax_load.html', function() {
Cufon.refresh('h3');
  });
}
```

but it doesnot work.. why ?

Comment: Just try `Cufon.refresh();` and see if it works. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906679/how-reload-refresh-styles-of-an-element-using-cufon-font-using-jquery/9907126#9907126)

Comment: looks like it works well !! i've tried this before, but apparently in a diffrent/wrong context. thaknk you, so much :)