# Jquery Toggle Link Color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Cufon and I have my navigation and all of my content is on one page and it is scrolling via anchor tag to that section of the page, yet the navigation stays visible I want when you click a link that link will light up:

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Veneer_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1 a', { 
        hover: true
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
h1 a.selected {
    color: red;
}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="home-link"><h1><a class="selected" href="#home">Home</a></h1></div>
<div class="hiw-link"><h1><a class="" href="#howitworks">How It Works</a></h1></div>
<div class="faq-link"><h1><a class="" href="#faq">Faq</a></h1></div>
<div class="prize-link"><h1><a class="" href="#prizes">Prizes</a></h1></div>
<div class="media-link"><h1><a class="" href="#media">Media</a></h1></div>
<div class="rules-link"><h1><a class="" href="#rules">Rules</a></h1></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#home-link','#hiw-link','#faq-link','#prize-link','#media-link','#rules-link').toggleClass(selected, addOrRemove);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically as you see I am just trying to add the class of selected to the anchor tag and remove it from everything else so only that link is red.  Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: note that you are using ID selectors for selecting elements by their class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ufacok/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('div[class$=link] h1 a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div[class$=link] h1 a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
    Cufon.refresh(); // Will refresh all `Cufon` text
});
```

Comment: So close!  It works but the color doesn't go away on the previously clicked items unless I rollover them??

Comment: @RobertTaylor Lol Robert! Now I got it! you're actually navigating to a new page! and how do you expect to pass some values cross page unless you read the URL with JS ? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, you are missing something. He is using `Cufon` and needs to call `Cufon.refresh();`, take a look at [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906679/how-reload-refresh-styles-of-an-element-using-cufon-font-using-jquery/9907126#9907126).

Comment: Just add `Cufon.refresh();` at last.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, Thank you Sheikh that fixed it!  Added that to Roko's code and everything works out great!  Thanks everyone

Comment: I thought Roko and you didn't see my comment so i answered it again, Welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Cufon text` so you need to call `Cufon.refresh();` after you change any class to `Cufon text`, otherwise it won't take effect.

```
$('div[class$=link] h1 a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div[class$=link] h1 a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
    Cufon.refresh(); // Will refresh all `Cufon` text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ID selectors, instead you should be using the class selectors (since you have home-link etc assigned to class attribute and not id attribute of the div elements)

Try this:

```
var selected = "selected"; //Assuming you are storing it in a variable
$(function(){
    var allLinks = $('.home-link,.hiw-link,.faq-link,.prize-link,.media-link,.rules-link');
    allLinks.click(function(e){
        allLinks.find("h1 > a").removeClass(selected);
        $(this).find("h1 > a").addClass(selected);
    });
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JsNBt/1/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, could it be because it's not looking for the class of the A tags?

Comment: @Chandu, [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906679/how-reload-refresh-styles-of-an-element-using-cufon-font-using-jquery/9907126#9907126).